# I dont know why the triangle still prints even though I exceeded the number I placed as a threshold

Tags: python

So I have basically the whole code done besides one thing thats really being a pain in my asscheeks, take a look(not at my asscheeks). Here the code prints out a triangle in "*" symbols. of course I gave the command that if the number is higher then 20 or less then 1 to not print anyhting. The message promts that its an "invalid input value" yet the triangle is still being outputted. I know this is a quick fix but I CANT FIND IT.

````
if rows < 1:
    print('Invalid input value. The numbers of rows cannot be less than 1.')
elif rows > 20:
    print('Invalid input value. The numbers of the rows cannot be greater than 20.')
    
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range((rows - i) - 1):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()```
````

Comment: No idea where rows is coming from, but based on your code it seems like it is either below 1 or over 20.  I suggest a complete code example so we can see where this is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

You just print messages when your input are out of bounds. You did nothing to prevent the triangle to print, once the error message is printed.

You probably meant (with a `else: do the rest`)

```py
if rows < 1:
    print('Invalid input value. The numbers of rows cannot be less than 1.')
elif rows > 20:
    print('Invalid input value. The numbers of the rows cannot be greater than 20.')
else:    
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range((rows - i) - 1):
            print(end=" ")
        for j in range(i + 1):
            print("*", end=" ")
        print()
```

Result for rows=10

```
         * 
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Okay so I did all that, but now the triangle is not printing out correctly, I think it might be in the indentation however I messed around with it but nothing seems to make it work. The previous issue was resolved however.

Comment: @MahmoodElshaer : seems to work fine for me. Of course I don't know what was expected exactly. But, well, it seems fine. I edited my post to include what my code outputs.